# HTML тег <s> осуждается или его можно использовать?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

HTML тег `<s>` осуждается, или его можно использовать? И где вообще самая достоверная информация?

Или лучше вообще использовать стили вместо тегов, где это можно?

Comment: [стандарт](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-s-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Использование `<s>` [спецификацией  не осуждается](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-s-element). Это вполне себе стандартный тег, который можно, и нужно использовать. Самая достоверная информация - в  [спецификации-рекомендации, опубликованной на W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) и в [их wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML). Остальное - порой отсебятина авторов.

А вот `<strike>`, кстати говоря, как раз [устарел и был исключен из стандарта](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#strike) - вместо него теперь нужно использовать `<del>` или `<s>`(в зависимости от ситуации)